# Why & Where Is This Script Returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

I'm attempting to use the following code to append a `#` (hashtag) to the URL to close lightboxes that were built utilizing the CSS `:target` attribute. This script executes on the keydown of the '*esc*' key just fine, but returns `example.com/#undefined` instead of just `example.com/#`.

I apologize for being a JS beginner, but how do I define it to return just the single `#`?

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
        var href = this.href;
        window.location.hash = href;
    }
});
```

Returns `#undefined` instead of just `#`.

Comment: try `var href = e.target.href || '';`, in the handler `this` refers to the document object which does not have the `href` property so `this.href` will return undefined

Comment: Because `this` no doubt doesn't have a `href` property or `this` is failing to target. Using your browsers console panel for debugging. `console.log(this);` If that returns undefined then `this` is the problem which my guess it is.

Comment: Can you give the html sample for this, where is the `href` suppose to come from

Comment: or `var href = $(e.target).closest('[href]').attr('href') || '';`

Comment: @ArunPJohny It was the `this.href` that was undefined. Your updated code works perfectly, it even removes the `#` from the URL. Thank you for updating with a great explanation as to why this was happening.

Comment: And what are you expecting `$('#').load(href);` to do?

Comment: @A.Wolff Oops that was leftover from earlier. I removed it from the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, in your handler `this` refers to the `document` object which does not have `href` property value. So your `href` variable has the value `undefined` thus the hash is updated as `undefined`.

Now a solution to the problem will depend on details that is not shared in the question like how is the html looks like, when and how it is suppose to work etc

You you want to get the `href` of the target element, then you can use

```
var href = e.target.href || '';
```

or

```
var href = $(e.target).closest('[href]').attr('href') || '';
```

Comment: Replacing the `var href` with your updated `var href = e.target.href || '';` code fixed it perfectly.

Comment: @MattBeckman You have better to use `var href = $(e.target).closest('[href]').attr('href') || '';` as e.g an anchor can contain other elements